# HTML is not showing via FTP to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, ftp

I am having a very annoying problem.

Edits that I make to an HTML file are not showing up on my site. I am using file zilla and when I upload css, it works perfectly on my live site. But for a html file I am editing it is not working. When I look at the page source it shows the space where my edit is, but its blank where the html should be.

Its not my cache, I have been using multiple compluters/ phones in different locations over the past weekend. My CSS file was uploaded perfectly, and when I redownload the html file from the website server back to my local computer the edit is showing!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several things that could be affecting it (mod_rewrites, server permissions, errors, etc).  Can you provide us with more information to give us a better idea of what is going on? Any error logs, URLs tried, expected vs actual result, etc.

Comment: I am just putting a div tag around a link, so my css can alter it. There are no errors. When I view page source I can click to my css file and look at all the edits I made. But my div tag is just not showing up.

Comment: I just remembered that I was not given a port for ftp. Does the port matter?

Comment: If you weren't given a port it probably defaults to FTP's default port which is 21.

Comment: A most unusual problem. Try changing the upload mode to binary instead of text, or visa/versa, unless the editor you are using is the problem.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the server. I deleated the main index file via ftp filezilla and the website was still live and working correctly 10 mins after. Anyways I just decided to do the work with another selector instead of putting in new divs and I fixed my issue with css. As far as the hosting server, I have no clue on whats going on or where to start. But thanks for all the fast reply's!

Answer (score 0):

try a different ftp client and re-input your ftp credentials and double check that the directory paths are lined up.
FY - transmit and fetch have free trials.